# How to display the days in 1 week in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I'm stuck, please help me how to display the cover days (e.g Monday, Tuesday, etc) per week. Please help me. Thank you!

Desired Sample Output:

```
Data,03/24/2014,Monday,20,Tuesday,30.....
Data,03/31/2014,Monday,12,Tuesday,20.....
```

Here's my script:

```
select 'Data'
||','||to_char(d.dtime_day, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
||','||nvl(g.total, 0)
from tablename d
left join (
        select trunc(t.create_time, 'IW') as ddate
              ,count(t.create_time) as total
        from tablename1 t
        left join tablename2 q
        on q.id = t.queue_id
        where t.create_time between trunc(sysdate,'IW')-12*7 and sysdate -1
        and q.name not like 'Data1%'
        or q.name not like 'Data2%'
        or q.name not like 'Data3%'
        or q.name not like 'Data4%'
        or q.name not like 'Data5%'
        or q.name not like 'Data6%'
        or q.name not like 'Data7%'
        or q.name not like 'Data8%'
        or q.name not like 'Data9%'
        group by trunc(t.create_time, 'IW')
) g on d.dtime_day = g.ddate
where d.dtime_day between trunc(sysdate,'IW')-12*7 and trunc(sysdate) -1
and trunc(d.dtime_day, 'IW')= d.dtime_day
order by d.dtime_day;
```

Output of the script:

```
Data,03/24/2014,42
Data,03/31/2014,25
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also select the day of the week using to_char e.g.

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'Day') from dual;
```

Comment: I think that's exactly what's needed

Comment: @ChrisProsser sorry but that's not the exactly that i need. i want to display the 7 days. e.g i have this query ||','||to_char(d.dtime_day, 'MM/dd/yyyy') so it display the everyday date and i have this in query d.dtime_day between trunc(sysdate,'IW') which is display weekly. and all i need is to display the days that covers in every week

Comment: @Yang Do the days need to be displayed as columns or can they be displayed as rows instead?

Comment: @ChrisProsser the days need to be displayed as rows in one column. I'll display those data in stacked column chart

Comment: @Yang I'm finding this a little difficult to picture. If you are able to provide the schema for the relevant tables and some sample data either in a sqlfiddle(http://sqlfiddle.com/) or in your question then I am happy to look at this further.

Comment: @ChrisProsser e.g i have a stacked column chart, the data displayed in the column of stacked chart are the date/days that cover in 1 week, probably from m-s and other stuff. And in the horizontal axis of the graph it will displayed the weekly date e.g 03/24/14    03/31/14

Answer (score 0):

Used in Oracle Apex for a LOV in a Form

```
   select  basic_day display, basic_day return
   from
   (select trim(to_char(basic_date, 'DAY')) basic_day
    from
    (   select 7 my_row, trunc(sysdate, 'DAY') basic_date
        from dual
        union
        select 1, trunc(sysdate, 'DAY') + 1
        from dual
        union
        select 2, trunc(sysdate, 'DAY') + 2
        from dual
        union
        select 3, trunc(sysdate, 'DAY') + 3
        from dual
        union
        select 4, trunc(sysdate, 'DAY') + 4
        from dual
        union
        select 5, trunc(sysdate, 'DAY') + 5
        from dual
        union
        select 6, trunc(sysdate, 'DAY') + 6
        from dual)
    order by  my_row
   )
```

Comment: While the answer is technically correct, this answers a question asked more than 8 years ago without adding information to another answer already provided. When answering check when the questions where asked and if there are already answers to the question. If your answer is not adding new information, it doesn't help.